# How to auto fit the canvas for editing the image in android

Tags: android, canvas, image-editing

I am trying draw on the image. Now I am using following class.

```
public class DrawingPaint extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint;
    public ArrayList<PathPoints> paths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
    private ArrayList<PathPoints> undonePaths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private int color;
    private int x, y;
    private String textToDraw = null;
    private boolean isTextModeOn = false;
    int lastColor = 0xFFFF0000;
    static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 15f;

    public DrawingPaint(Context context/*, int color*/) {
        super(context);
        //this.color = color;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        /*mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        mPaint.setTextSize(30);

        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false));
        mCanvas = new Canvas();*/
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {

        mPaint = new Paint();
        this.color = color;
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        mPaint.setTextSize(30);

       mPath = new Path();
       paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false));
       mCanvas = new Canvas();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // mBitmap = AddReportItemActivity.mPhoto;
        mBitmap = CustomGalleryHandler.getmInstance().getBitmapSend();
        float xscale = (float) w / (float) mBitmap.getWidth();
        float yscale = (float) h / (float) mBitmap.getHeight();
        if (xscale > yscale) // make sure both dimensions fit (use the
            // smaller scale)
            xscale = yscale;
        float newx = (float) w * xscale;
        float newy = (float) h * xscale; // use the same scale for both
        // dimensions
        // if you want it centered on the display (black borders)
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, this.getWidth(),
                this.getHeight(), true);
        // mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        for (PathPoints p : paths) {
            mPaint.setColor(p.getColor());
            Log.v("", "Color code : " + p.getColor());
            if (p.isTextToDraw()) {
                canvas.drawText(p.textToDraw, p.x, p.y, mPaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), mPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false));

    }

    private void drawText(int x, int y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        paths.add(new PathPoints(color, textToDraw, true, x, y));
        // mCanvas.drawText(textToDraw, x, y, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (!isTextModeOn) {
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!isTextModeOn) {
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (isTextModeOn) {
                    drawText((int) x, (int) y);
                    invalidate();
                } else {
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        try {
            if (paths.size() > 0) {
                undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
                invalidate();
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.toString();
        }

    }

    public void onClickRedo() {
        try {

           if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
                paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
                invalidate();
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

The following method is used in Activity extended class

```
public class GalleryImageFullScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ImageView mFullScreenImage;
private ImageView /*mWhiteColor,*//* mGreenColor, mSkyBlueColor, mYellowColor, mRedColor, mBlackColor,*/ mUndoIcon,
mPaintImageSave, mPaintImageDelete, mRedoIcon;
RoundedImageView mWhiteColor, mGreenColor, mSkyBlueColor, mYellowColor, mRedColor, mBlackColor;
// private Signature mSignature;
private RelativeLayout mDrawLayout;
private DrawingPaint mDrawViewSignature;
private AlertDialog  mAlertDialog = null;
Bitmap bitmapss;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_fullscreen);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mUndoIcon =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.erase_icon);
    mFullScreenImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_fullscreen);
    mDrawLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.img_fullscreen_layout);
    mPaintImageSave=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.paint_img_save);
    mPaintImageDelete=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.paint_img_delete);
    mRedoIcon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_redo);
    mWhiteColor.setOnClickListener(this);
    mGreenColor.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSkyBlueColor.setOnClickListener(this);
    mYellowColor.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRedColor.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBlackColor.setOnClickListener(this);
    mUndoIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPaintImageSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPaintImageDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRedoIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
   // mSignature = new Signature(GalleryImageFullScreen.this, null);

    try {
        Intent i=getIntent();
        Bitmap  image = null;

        image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
                CustomGalleryHandler.getmInstance().setBitmapSend(image);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;

        mDrawLayout.getLayoutParams().width = imageWidth;
        mDrawLayout.getLayoutParams().height = imageHeight;
        //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_description = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageHeight);
       // mDrawLayout.setLayoutParams(layout_description);

        Bitmap mSignatureBitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth,
                imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mDrawViewSignature = new DrawingPaint(GalleryImageFullScreen.this/*, lastColor*/);
        mDrawViewSignature.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mDrawViewSignature.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        mDrawViewSignature.layout(0, 0, mDrawViewSignature.getMeasuredWidth(),
                mDrawViewSignature.getMeasuredHeight());
        mDrawViewSignature.buildDrawingCache(true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mSignatureBitmapImage);
        Drawable bgDrawable = mDrawLayout.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null) {
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        mDrawLayout.draw(canvas);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mSignatureBitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.d("", "" + e.toString());
    }
    mDrawViewSignature.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    mDrawLayout.addView(mDrawViewSignature);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.paint_img_save:
            try {
                Bitmap editedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawViewSignature
                        .getDrawingCache());
                editedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(editedImage, mDrawViewSignature.getWidth(), mDrawViewSignature.getHeight(),
                        true);
                if(editedImage!=null) {
                    final Bitmap finalEditedImage = editedImage;
                    mAlertDialog = Alerts.getInstance().createConfirmationDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.painting_image_save), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            /*Bitmap editedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawViewSignature
                                    .getDrawingCache());
                            editedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(editedImage, mDrawViewSignature.getWidth(), mDrawViewSignature.getHeight(),
                                    true);*/
                            //saveImageToInternalStorage(finalEditedImage);
                            storeImage(finalEditedImage);
                            PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().setEditedURL(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
                            callToGalleyActivity();
                            mAlertDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    mAlertDialog.show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.d("paint_img_save",""+e.toString());
            }
            break;
        case R.id.paint_img_delete:
            try {
                if (!PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen().equals("") && !PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen().equals("null")) {
                    mAlertDialog = Alerts.getInstance().createConfirmationDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.painting_image_path_delete), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                          //  DatabaseHelper.getInstance().deleteParticularVideoPath(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
                            CustomGalleryHandler.getmInstance().deleteParticularImages(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
                            CustomGalleryHandler.getmInstance().deleteParticularImageFromInternalStorage(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
                            callToGalleyActivity();
                            mAlertDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
                mAlertDialog.show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.d("paint_img_delete",""+e.toString());
            }
            break;
        case R.id.img_redo:
            mDrawViewSignature.onClickRedo();
            break;
    }
}


private void saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    try {

        File myDir = new File(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Logger.d("ListOfPhoto",""+myDir.getAbsolutePath());
        Logger.d("ListOfPhotoRename",""+PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
        for(File files: myDir.listFiles())
        {
            Logger.d("ListOfPhoto",""+files.getAbsolutePath());
            Logger.d("ListOfPhotoRename",""+PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
        }
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen()).skipMemoryCache();
        /*Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + "3680" + ".png";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }*/
        try {
            if(myDir.exists())
            {
                myDir.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.d("saveImageToInternalStorage",""+e.toString());
    }
}

private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = new File(PreferenceForCustomCamera.getInstance().getImagePathForGalleryFullScreen());
    if (pictureFile.exists()) {
        pictureFile.delete();
    }
    //clearImageDiskCache();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.d("GalleryImage", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.d("GalleryImage", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}


public boolean clearImageDiskCache() {

    File cache = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "picasso-cache");
    if (cache.exists() && cache.isDirectory()) {
        return deleteDir(cache);

    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}

}
```

The following code used in my xml for draw.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_fullscreen_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_components_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_fullscreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

It is working fine when I use Landscape images. But when I use Portrait image, image getting stretched. Please let me know how to make the canvas fit to the image.

Thanks in advance

I alter this code:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
        RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth-10, imageHeight-10);
        m.setRectToRect(inRect, outRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        Bitmap mSignatureBitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image,0,0,imageWidth,
                imageHeight, m,true);
```

I used this code also. But Not working:

```
Matrix m = mFullScreenImage.getImageMatrix();
            RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
            RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, mFullScreenImage.getWidth(), mFullScreenImage.getHeight());
            m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            Bitmap mSignatureBitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image,0,0,imageWidth,
                    imageHeight, m,true);
```

Comment: use `Bitmap#createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)` setup your `Matrix` by calling `Matrix#setRectToRect`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the instant response. Here how to give x and y? Can you give any sample for this. Please.

Comment: fron the docs: `x - The x coordinate of the first pixel in source
,y - The y coordinate of the first pixel in source`

Comment: No luck.. It's not make any changes. :-(

Comment: post your code then

Comment: I posted the entire code.. Please check and let me know..

Comment: you are not using `Bitmap#createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)` anywhere

Comment: I revert back that.. Because of no changes.

Comment: so you did something wrong since it works like a charm

Comment: @pskink.. I added that code also in the end. But when I add this code app crashes and howing nullpointer exeption.

Comment: i didn't say to use `postScale`, i said: `setup your Matrix by calling Matrix#setRectToRect`

Comment: I updated the Matrix#setRectToRect. But no luck @pskink.. Sorry for more troubling.. But you can help me. Please.

Comment: I used another code also. But Not working. And one more note I am using tablet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121938/discussion-between-new-developer-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink.. I posted one more question about this draw and save the image. Can you help me on that?? Please. [Question is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199538/how-to-save-the-edited-canvas-to-image-in-android).